# showing a value in a radio button as label in another page

Tags: html, asp.net, query-string

I am a newbie to asp.net. I have a registration page where I record their info. I have to show the user's sex (male/female) as a label in the page after submission of the registration form.

I know using the same concept with text values (for example-- http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/10/query-string-in-aspnet-example-c-vbnet.html), but how to use it with radio group.

Thanks, it may seem silly to some, but as I am newbie to html and asp.net please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept is similar to passing text values. When an item is selected in RadioButtonList the selected value is stored in `.SelectedValue` property. So you can do something like:

```
Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx?UserSex = " + RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: @yuriy...thanks for the answer, but do you have some useful links regarding that, i am trying too, but that will be useful.

Comment: @user3029284 the usage is exactly as in the link you yourself provided. Only instead of TextBox.Text you append RadioButtonList.SelectedValue to the query string.